# Where can I find a description of the CryptoNight hash algorithm?

Tags: cryptonight, algorithm

Where can I find a description of the CryptoNight hash algorithm?

Both a thorough and ELI5 description of the hash algorithm would be appreciated

Comment: (hello, this is my first post) in the [code](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/crypto/slow-hash.c#L543) I see just at the beginning… > #define MEMORY (1 << 21) // 2MB scratchpad
> #define ITER (1 << 20) Question… is the 2MB "chunk" fixed… or can I use an other value as well ? in the mean Time, I learned that "Monero" with 1MB already exists… it is called "aeon"… an other crypto currency.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The description of the CryptoNight hash algorithm and the steps it performs can be found in the [code](https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/blob/master/src/crypto/slow-hash.c#L543) as well as in a written file by the CryptoNote team, which can be found [here](https://cryptonote.org/cns/cns008.txt). Lastly, in his blog, professor David Anderson also briefly describes the CryptoNight algorithm with an accompanying [graph](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-NJddW0tx9j0/U_6C2wgXSAI/AAAAAAAAkDk/nyKkOESWgwI/s1600/cryptonight.png) that illustrates it. From the blog:

> This was a brilliantly designed proof-of-work function targeting the strengths of modern CPUs -- native AES encryption and fast 64 bit multipliers -- tuned to use a scratchpad exactly the size of the per-core L3 cache on Intel CPUs (about 2MB) that someone then wrapped in such a thick blanket of crap it was nearly unrecognizable until you started jumping in, tearing it apart, and putting it back together again.
>
> [Here's](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-NJddW0tx9j0/U_6C2wgXSAI/AAAAAAAAkDk/nyKkOESWgwI/s1600/cryptonight.png) what it looks like without the crud (diagram shows one round):  Some initial 128 bit values are determined by hashing the block state using a Keccak (sha3) variant - call them A and B.  The big lookup table is also populated using that same state, mixed around using AES.  Then, executed 500,000 times, are rounds of mixing as shown at the right:  Use A to determine a pseudorandom location in the scratchpad, take that, mix it in, AES encrypt it (one round), use the result to determine a second location, use that in a 64 bit multiply, store it back, and repeat.  Elegantly simple.

Comment: original article [here](https://da-data.blogspot.com/2014/08/minting-money-with-monero-and-cpu.html)

Answer (score 5):

The algorithm is described in [Cryptonote Standard 008](https://cryptonote.org/cns/cns008.txt).