# Hash rate of CPU is the same as that of GPU

Tags: cpu-mining, gpu-mining

My GPU:gtx1050ti
My cpu: ryzen 5 1500x
Both of them have a same H/s of 320.
I'm using xmr-stack for both. Nvidia version for GPU and CPU for CPU.
Why is it so?

Comment: Probably just a coincidence. Can you comment or edit your post to state if you get an increased hashrate on one or both of you run them independently rather than simultaneously?

Comment: @jwinterm it's the same independently or individuallly for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect the GPU to be much faster, your question may be answered here: [Is it better to mine with a CPU or GPU](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1386/is-it-better-to-mine-with-a-cpu-or-gpu)

Your numbers sound reasonable for the CPU, and mostly consistent with reported numbers for the GPU. That said, I've got a bit better performance out of XMR-Stak than ccminer on my GTX 950 card. I also made a test of numerous configurations for blocks and threads for my card, and there are certainly numerous settings that will cause it to underperform.

I am running XMR-Stak-CPU and XMR-Stak-NVIDIA, and can share my rates for some of the workers for comparison if that's any help.

```
AMD FX-6300 Six-Core Processor   : 274 H/s
  > low_power_mode on 1/6 cores

NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950           : 251 H/s
  > 32 threads x 18 blocks

Intel i7-7700K @ 4.20GHz         : 340 H/s
  > low_power_mode on 0/4 cores

2 x Intel Xeon E5-2620 @ 2.00GHz : 288 H/s
  > low_power_mode on 2/12 cores
```

I run all of these on headless Linux, mostly Ubuntu 16.04, and with the latest CUDA.