# Compile any miner into assembly for WebAssembly

Tags: cpu-mining, mining

I am trying to push my own skill way beyond what I should. I'm a moderate web developer with years of experience, but I've recently become more active with code running faster in the browser, which can be done with WebAssembly and asm.js.

Monero is amazing because of it's CPU-only CryptoNight algorithm. I've been wanting to try this out in the browser, without using something like Coinhive. I guess what I really want compiled and working is [slow-hash.c](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/crypto/slow-hash.c) but I'm not really sure.

Has anyone ever done this before, successfully, except Coinhive?

Comment: Note: CryptoNight is not "CPU-only", also [works well with GPUs](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1386/is-it-better-to-mine-with-a-cpu-or-gpu).

Answer (score 1):

i havent seen it implimented in this way anywhere else. there is jsecoin that is emerging with similar setup.
i am no programmer but have been looking at exactly the same thing since discovering coin hive. i think a web page that enables people to use a simple miner like xmr stak cpu would be a great way to get people introduced to monero etc. i would like to set up a page that points to a pool i use instead of coinhive.

Comment: Welcome to Monero! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//monero.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//monero.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.