# Low Hashrate for Some Nodes in Pool

Tags: mining-pools, hashrate

I have a lot of identical nodes all connected to the SXMR pool. They are CPU mining on 40 real cores (hyperthreading is disabled in BIOS) but I am finding that some nodes are performing far slower than other ones.

[image: Example of Node with Low Hashrate]

My question here is, am I doing something incorrect? Should I not connect the ~100 nodes I have to the same pool? Could this simply be a performance impact from having all of these nodes making an upstream connection? Is this just a matter of hash availability?

I'm aware that I'm not getting the maximum I could out of these due to 1 in every 10 nodes not performing anywhere near as well as the others.

Answer (score 3):

The problem may be that CryptoNight is a memory-intensive PoW algorithm.  For effective mining, you need 2MB of L3 cache per core.

[Here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/1115/234)'s an interesting answer describing CryptoNight.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm still a bit confused as to how this would effect only some of the nodes (seeing as they're all identical). If it is a matter of not having enough L3 cache per core then all of the nodes should be effected by this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have hundreds of miners, you should have a look at [xmr-node-proxy](https://github.com/Snipa22/xmr-node-proxy), it reduces load on the pool servers and allows for easier configuration of your miners.